# Could not access theme on website(2 domain points to same directory) which has been setup using plesk panel

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-hosting, plesk

On windows server 2008 R2 using plesk panel i have created 2 domains ( domain1.com & domain2.com) and as result it has created 2 directory in inetpub/vhost for domain1.com & domain2.com now i have put web application files in **domain1.com/httpdocs** and for domain2.com from IIS-> advance setting set physical path to domain1.com/httpdocs so now both 
domains points to same directory

**Now when i am accessing site with domain2.com and at first page(login page) i could not access theme, why?**

To resolved this i have setup **"Everyone"** rights in domain1.com/httpdocs folder and it was resolved but i think after server recycling (web24) it would remove that rights. so what is exact way to setup rights here using plesk panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now when i am accessing site with domain2.com and at first page(login
>   page) i could not access theme, why?

Because IIS tries to access to files with permissions of user which is specified for exact virtual host, and this user is not same for different virtual hosts.

But I don't understand what you actually trying to do? 
If you need a domain alias, there is able to create it in plesk.